Proving that $0 = \pi - \frac{\pi^5}{5!} - \frac{\pi^7}{7!} + \frac{\pi^{11}}{11!} + \frac{\pi^{13}}{13!} - \frac{\pi^{17}}{17!}-\cdots$
I'm looking for a proof that: $0 = \pi - \frac{\pi^5}{5!} - \frac{\pi^7}{7!} + \frac{\pi^{11}}{11!} + \frac{\pi^{13}}{13!} - \frac{\pi^{17}}{17!}- \frac{\pi^{19}}{19!} + \frac{\pi^{23}}{23!}+\cdots$.
The sequence is not, as might be thought, $1$ and the primes greater than $3$, but rather the numbers congruent to $1$ or $5$ mod $6$. So far the only path I can see to prove the identity is to prove that:
$(2n-1)\pi + \frac{[(2n-1)\pi]^3}{3!} - \frac{[(2n-1)\pi]^7}{7!}-\frac{[(2n-1)\pi]^9}{9!} + \cdots =\frac{[(2n-1)\pi]^3}{3!}+\frac{[(2n-1)\pi]^5}{5!} - \frac{[(2n-1)\pi]^9}{9!} - \frac{[(2n-1)\pi]^{11}}{11!} + \cdots = (-1)^{n-1} \cosh\Big(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(2n-1)\pi\Big).$
Then subtract the second series from the first and set $n = 1$. But I'm having a hard time to find a way to prove that as well (I found those identities empirically).
I know that Euler found the somewhat similar identities:
$1-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{11}+\cdots = \frac{\pi}{3} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.
$1-\frac{1}{5^3}+\frac{1}{7^3} - \frac{1}{11^3}+\cdots = \Big(\frac{\pi}{3}\Big)^3 \cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.
Is there some way to morph either of them into the ones I want to prove?Besides that, I also know the sum of the related series: $\pi + \frac{\pi^5}{5!} - \frac{\pi^7}{7!} - \frac{\pi^{11}}{11!} + \frac{\pi^{13}}{13!} + \cdots= \dfrac{e^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\pi}+e^{-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\pi}}{3}$.
But I don't see how that helps.

Hint: Consider the Taylor series for $\sin(x)$

1/ Do you know the function whose Maclaurin series is $ \sum \frac{ x^k}{k!}$? 2/ Suppose the series if $f(x)$, then what is the Maclaurin series for $f(x) + f(-x)$? 3/ How can we use that to find the Maclaurin series for the mod 12 pattern that you have?

I think my approach would be to calculate the real part of $e^{i\pi/6} \sinh(\pi e^{i\pi/3})$ two different ways.

It's not clear what $\pi$ is at this level.

Here is the main idea, consider the functions
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n!} = xe^x
$$
and
$$
g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+5}}{n!} = x^5e^x
$$
if $\omega = e^{i\frac{\pi}{6}}$, check that (see what happens to the general term in the cases of congruence you commented)
$$
F(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{5} f(i\omega^k x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} i^{6n+6}\frac{x^{6n+6}}{(6n+5)!} = x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{6n+5}}{(6n+5)!}
$$
and
$$
G(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{5} g(i\omega^k x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} i^{6n+6}\frac{x^{6n+6}}{(6n+1)!} = x^5\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{6n+1}}{(6n+1)!}
$$
now notice that the sum that you want is
$$
\frac{F(\pi)}{\pi} - \frac{G(\pi)}{\pi^5}
$$
now just evaluate this to see that it is zero.

I'm getting $\sum_{k=0}^5 \omega^{kn}=\begin{cases} 6 & n \equiv 0 \mod 6 \ 0 & n \not\equiv 0 \mod 6\end{cases}$. Where are you getting the powers of $-1$?

@angryavian I made a mistake, it should be $i\omega^k x$ instead of $\omega^k x$, I will edit it

$\newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}$
$\newcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}$
This question is about simplifying a series of the form
$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\chi(r)\frac{t^r}{r!}$$ for some value of $t$, where $\chi$ is a Dirichlet character modulo $q$. So let $\tau_{(\cdot)}(\chi)$ be the corresponding Gauss sum
$$\tau_a(\chi)=\sum_{r=0}^{q-1}\chi(r)\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i}ar/q}\text{.}$$
Then since
$$\chi(r)=\frac{1}{q}\sum_{a=0}^{q-1}\tau_a(\chi)\mathrm{e}^{-2\pi\mathrm{i}ar/q}$$
we have
$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\chi(r)\frac{t^r}{r!}=\frac{1}{q}\sum_{a=0}^{q-1}\tau_a(\chi)\exp\left(\e^{-2\pi\i a/q}t\right)\text{.}$$
In the present situation, $\chi(r)=\chi_{12}(11,r)$ is a particular Dirichlet character modulo $12$ (LMFDB) for which it happens that
$$\tau_a(\chi_{12}(11,\cdot))=\sqrt{12}\chi_{12}(11,r)\text{,}$$
whence
$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\chi_{12}(11,r)\frac{t^r}{r!}=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}\left(
\exp\left((\tfrac{\sqrt{3}+\i}{2})t\right)
-\exp\left((\tfrac{-\sqrt{3}+\i}{2})t\right)
-\exp\left((\tfrac{-\sqrt{3}-\i}{2})t\right)
+\exp\left((\tfrac{\sqrt{3}-\i}{2})t\right)\right)$$
or
$$\boxed{\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\chi_{12}(11,r)\frac{t^r}{r!}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\sinh\tfrac{\sqrt{3}\,t}{2}\cos\tfrac{t}{2}}\text{.}$$
This last expression vanishes at $t=\pi$, yielding the desired result.
